# Traverse an Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: data-structures, abstract-syntax-tree

I plunged in an attemp to translate Haskell.

**I need walk** the *HsModule structure* (returned by parseModule source),
  **to translate every** *HsIdent String*, where String is an english identifier
  **into** *HsIdent String*, where String is an identifier in some other natural language (i.e. italian, french, ...).

I wonder if exists some direct strategy, perhaps in TH, to walk a HsModule Structure (i.e. to apply a function to every HsIdent String), without explicit unfold-functions for the involved substructures?

I hope I was plain enough in my request; many thanks for your precious aid.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in Data.Generics packages.

HsModule is an instance of *Data* and *Typeable*, so it is eligible to process it with a traverse function of a Generic package. I chose [SYB](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.3.7) because is quite well [documented](http://web.archive.org/web/20080622204226/http://www.cs.vu.nl/boilerplate/) .

My solution is:

```
module Main where

import Data.Generics
import Language.Haskell.Syntax
import Language.Haskell.Parser
import Language.Haskell.Pretty
import Control.Monad

translate:: ParseResult HsModule -> Maybe String
translate r = case r of
                ParseOk a -> Just (show $ prettyPrint $ translateHsIdent "_italian" a)
                ParseFailed _ _ -> Nothing

translateHsIdent :: Data a => String -> a -> a
translateHsIdent k = everywhere (mkT (addStrangerIdentifier k))
    where
      addStrangerIdentifier :: String -> HsName -> HsName
      addStrangerIdentifier s (HsIdent i) = HsIdent (i ++ s)

main = maybe (putStrLn "Parse Error") putStrLn result
    where 
      result :: Maybe String
      result = translate $ parseModule "main = putStrLn \"Just a Try\""
```

I hope it can be useful for someone else.